# Touchpad gestures without touchegg

Tags: touchpad

I have a FocalTech touchpad, which has its whole area sensitive to touch. Therefore touchegg doesn't work as expected - if I try to select some text while holding the left button and swiping, a drag gesture is detected. This behavior is not present when using the stock two finger scrolling.

Is it possible to program touchpad gestures, e.g. switching workspace with two fingers without using touchegg?

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon

Comment: I am using touchegg on Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon too. Desktop with magic trackpad. Sometimes touchegg became frozen and touchpad stops working. I need kill touchegg process and restart it. The question is intresting for me.